# Catch router password

Tags: wireless-networking, router, passwords

I'm doing experiment with my friend and my router, forcing it's all security.
Our task now it to catch login and password, when someone is logging in from a smartphone (wifi).

Anyone who can help us?

Router: TP-LINK TL-WR740N

Comment: TP-LINK TL-WR740N

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the communications (an the authentication more) with the router are ciphered so it's hard to obtain the text.

A good tool to start is Wireshark. A packet analyzer that helps you to analyze network traffic. It's a very powerfull tool but it's not easy to use. You will be able to see the authentication packets, but you will not be able to decrypt it.

Another way to obtain the user/password is doing a "man in the middle attack", but be care, it's illegal do this in a third person network.

Comment: Router fortunately has no encryption.
Is it going to work to catch other's packets?

Comment: If you have the network password (or not password in this case) you can sniffer the packets if your wireless card supports monitor mode and then decrypt it. I recommend you follow a [guide](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) to start capturing packets. Once you could capture the wireless packets you should learn how to filter it and interpret it.

Comment: One more question, is wireless network card completely necessary to capture wireless packets?

Comment: Many wireless integrated cards support monitor mode, but not all. Usually with an special driver you don't need to buy an external wireless device.